# How to use iOS (Swift) SceneKit SCNSceneRenderer unprojectPoint properly

Tags: ios, 3d, swift, scenekit

I'm developing some code using SceneKit on iOS and in my code I want to determine the x and y coordinates on the global z plane where z is 0.0 and x and y are determined from a tap gesture. MY setup is as follows:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light.color = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    let triangleNode = SCNNode()
    triangleNode.geometry = defineTriangle();
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(triangleNode)

    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as SCNView

    // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene

    // configure the view
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    // add a tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    let gestureRecognizers = NSMutableArray()
    gestureRecognizers.addObject(tapGesture)
    scnView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers
}

func handleTap(gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as SCNView
    // check what nodes are tapped
    let p = gestureRecognize.locationInView(scnView)
    // get the camera
    var camera = scnView.pointOfView.camera

    // screenZ is percentage between z near and far
    var screenZ = Float((15.0 - camera.zNear) / (camera.zFar - camera.zNear))
    var scenePoint = scnView.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3Make(Float(p.x), Float(p.y), screenZ))
    println("tapPoint: (\(p.x), \(p.y)) scenePoint: (\(scenePoint.x), \(scenePoint.y), \(scenePoint.z))")
}

func defineTriangle() -> SCNGeometry {

    // Vertices
    var vertices:[SCNVector3] = [
        SCNVector3Make(-2.0, -2.0, 0.0),
        SCNVector3Make(2.0, -2.0, 0.0),
        SCNVector3Make(0.0, 2.0, 0.0)
    ]

    let vertexData = NSData(bytes: vertices, length: vertices.count * sizeof(SCNVector3))
    var vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(data: vertexData,
        semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex,
        vectorCount: vertices.count,
        floatComponents: true,
        componentsPerVector: 3,
        bytesPerComponent: sizeof(Float),
        dataOffset: 0,
        dataStride: sizeof(SCNVector3))

    // Normals
    var normals:[SCNVector3] = [
        SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    ]

    let normalData = NSData(bytes: normals, length: normals.count * sizeof(SCNVector3))
    var normalSource = SCNGeometrySource(data: normalData,
        semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal,
        vectorCount: normals.count,
        floatComponents: true,
        componentsPerVector: 3,
        bytesPerComponent: sizeof(Float),
        dataOffset: 0,
        dataStride: sizeof(SCNVector3))

    // Indexes
    var indices:[CInt] = [0, 1, 2]
    var indexData  = NSData(bytes: indices, length: sizeof(CInt) * indices.count)
    var indexElement = SCNGeometryElement(
        data: indexData,
        primitiveType: .Triangles,
        primitiveCount: 1,
        bytesPerIndex: sizeof(CInt)
    )

    var geo = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource, normalSource], elements: [indexElement])

    // material
    var material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents  = UIColor.redColor()
    material.doubleSided = true
    material.shininess = 1.0;
    geo.materials = [material];

    return geo
}
```

As you can see. I have a triangle that is 4 units tall by 4 units wide and set on the z plane (z = 0) centered at x, y (0.0, 0.0). The camera is the default SCNCamera which looks in the negative z direction and I've placed it at (0, 0, 15). The default value for zNear and zFar are 1.0 and 100.0 respectively. In my handleTap method, I take the x and y screen coordinates of the tap and attempt to find the x and y global scene coordinates where z = 0.0. I'm using a call to unprojectPoint.

The docs for unprojectPoint indicate

> Unprojecting a point whose z-coordinate is 0.0 returns a point on the
>   near clipping plane; unprojecting a point whose z-coordinate is 1.0
>   returns a point on the far clipping plane.

While it does not specifically say that for the points in between there is a liner relationship between the near and far plane, I have made that assumption and calculate the value of screenZ to be the percent distance between the near and far plane that the z = 0 plane is located. To check my answer, I can click near the corners of the triangle because I know where they are in global coordinates.

My problem is that I'm not getting the correct values and I'm not getting consistent values when I start changing the zNear and zFar clipping planes on the camera. So my question is, how can I do do this? In the end, I'm going to create a new piece of geometry and place it on the z-plane corresponding to where the user clicked.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you have an issue where unprojectPoint returned effectively the same values for the X and Y coordinates?

Comment: Have you looked into `SCNSceneRenderer.hitTest()` ? The documentation of `unprojectPoint()` even mentions you should use `hitTest()` for click events.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Typical depth buffers in a 3D graphics pipeline [are not linear](https://youtube.com/watch?v=EIihUx0SSrs). Perspective division [causes depths in normalized device coordinates to be on a different scale](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20Perspective%20Projection.html). ([See also here](http://www.learnopengles.com/understanding-opengls-matrices/).)

So the z-coordinate you're feeding into `unprojectPoint` isn't actually the one you want.

How, then, to find the normalized-depth coordinate matching a plane in world space? Well, it helps if that plane is orthogonal to the camera -- which yours is. Then all you need to do is project a point on that plane:

```
let projectedOrigin = gameView.projectPoint(SCNVector3Zero)
```

Now you have the location of the world origin in 3D view + normalized-depth space. To map other points in 2D view space onto this plane, use the z-coordinate from this vector:

```
let vp = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(scnView)
let vpWithZ = SCNVector3(x: vp.x, y: vp.y, z: projectedOrigin.z)
let worldPoint = gameView.unprojectPoint(vpWithZ)
```

This gets you a point in world space that maps the click/tap location to the z = 0 plane, suitable for use as the `position` of a node if you want to show that location to the user.

(Note that this approach works only as long as you're mapping onto a plane that's perpendicular to the camera's view direction. If you want to map view coordinates onto a differently-oriented surface, the normalized-depth value in `vpWithZ` won't be constant.)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for spending the time to answer this. Cheers!

Comment: I was just searching for the exact same issue as ptoinon....couldn't find anything....could not figure out how this works. Thanks a lot rickster!!!!

Comment: What if you wanted to project a 2D coordinate onto an arbitrary point in front of the camera (e.g., 15 units in front of the camera)?

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks a lot @rickster!
For future googlers, in my case I needed the node to be at a Z position of 10 units in front of camera. Only adjustment needed to work was to replace `SCNVector3Zero` for `SCNVector3Make(0, 0, myNode.position.z)` -note that I had already placed it at my desired depth-

Comment: Hi @Crashalot, I am wondering whether this could apply to face tracking from the 3D mesh to 2D image point. Could you help?!

Comment: This works, but the issue is that if the view is resized the position is wrong because it belongs to the old view coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

After some experimentation, here's what we developed to project a touch point to a given point in the scene for some arbitrary depth.

The modification you need is to compute the intersection of the Z=0 plane with this line, and that will be your point.

```
private func touchPointToScenePoint(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> SCNVector3 {
    // Get touch point
    let touchPoint = recognizer.locationInView(sceneView)

    // Compute near & far points
    let nearVector = SCNVector3(x: Float(touchPoint.x), y: Float(touchPoint.y), z: 0)
    let nearScenePoint = sceneView.unprojectPoint(nearVector)
    let farVector = SCNVector3(x: Float(touchPoint.x), y: Float(touchPoint.y), z: 1)
    let farScenePoint = sceneView.unprojectPoint(farVector)

    // Compute view vector
    let viewVector = SCNVector3(x: Float(farScenePoint.x - nearScenePoint.x), y: Float(farScenePoint.y - nearScenePoint.y), z: Float(farScenePoint.z - nearScenePoint.z))

    // Normalize view vector
    let vectorLength = sqrt(viewVector.x*viewVector.x + viewVector.y*viewVector.y + viewVector.z*viewVector.z)
    let normalizedViewVector = SCNVector3(x: viewVector.x/vectorLength, y: viewVector.y/vectorLength, z: viewVector.z/vectorLength)

    // Scale normalized vector to find scene point
    let scale = Float(15)
    let scenePoint = SCNVector3(x: normalizedViewVector.x*scale, y: normalizedViewVector.y*scale, z: normalizedViewVector.z*scale)

    print("2D point: \(touchPoint). 3D point: \(nearScenePoint). Far point: \(farScenePoint). scene point: \(scenePoint)")

    // Return <scenePoint>
    return scenePoint
}
```

Comment: As I add more nodes to the screen using the above scenePoint result, the nodes position becomes more inaccurate by moving further away from the touch point.  It seems like the scenePoint starts to return a position closer to previously placed nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for getting the exact point in 3d Space.

```
// If the object is in 0,0,0 point you can use
float zDepth = [self projectPoint:SCNVector3Zero].z;

// or myNode.position.
//zDepth = [self projectPoint:myNode.position].z;

NSLog(@"2D point: X %f, Y: %f, zDepth: %f", click.x, click.y, zDepth);

SCNVector3 worldPoint = [self unprojectPoint:SCNVector3Make(click.x, click.y,  zDepth)];

SCNVector3 nearVec = SCNVector3Make(click.x, click.y, 0.0);
SCNVector3 nearPoint = [self unprojectPoint:nearVec];

SCNVector3 farVec = SCNVector3Make(click.x, click.y, 1.0);
SCNVector3 farPoint = [self unprojectPoint:farVec];

float z_magnitude = fabs(farPoint.z - nearPoint.z);
float near_pt_factor = fabs(nearPoint.z) / z_magnitude;
float far_pt_factor = fabs(farPoint.z) / z_magnitude;

GLKVector3 nearP = GLKVector3Make(nearPoint.x, nearPoint.y, nearPoint.z);
GLKVector3 farP = GLKVector3Make(farPoint.x, farPoint.y, farPoint.z);

GLKVector3 final_pt = GLKVector3Add(GLKVector3MultiplyScalar(nearP, far_pt_factor), GLKVector3MultiplyScalar(farP, near_pt_factor));

NSLog(@"3D world point = %f, %f, %f", final_pt.x, final_pt.y, worldPoint.z);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `zDepth` be a float from 0 to 1 if you're going to use it in `unprojectPoint`?

Comment: No necesary. I currently use the functions provided by SCeneKit, this code is no longer used.

Comment: What is GLKVector3Add ?