# SceneKit: unprojectPoint returns same/similar point no matter where you touch screen

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit, scnnode, sceneview

The code below should translate touch coordinates into world coordinates for a SceneKit scene.

However, as illustrated by the output below, the point returned by `unprojectPoint` returns effectively the same point no matter where you touch on the screen (iPhone 5s).

The class docs for `unprojectPoint` suggest using Z values between 0 and 1, but using different values like 0.5 did not change the output for `unprojectPoint`.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150737/how-to-use-ios-swift-scenekit-scnscenerenderer-unprojectpoint-properly) discusses how to set the depth value for `unprojectPoint`, but setting the Z value to values greater than 1 (e.g., 15, 20) also did not change the output.

In both cases, the X and Y values return from `unprojectPoint` effectively remained the same as well.

1) What is the right way to use `unprojectPoint`?

2) How does `unprojectPoint` account for camera rotations? For instance, if you moved the camera to (0, 20, 0) and rotated the camera down 90 degrees so it's facing the ground, how do you ensure the rotation is accounted for? If you set a depth of 20 and tapped on the origin, the desired return value from `unprojectPoint` should be (0, 0, 0).

3) How do you get `unprojectPoint` to return values in front of the camera (e.g., Z values are lower than the camera's Z value)

**Code:**

```
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: Float(0), z: Float(8))

func sceneViewTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = recognizer.locationInView(sceneView)
    let unprojectPoint = SCNVector3(x: Float(point.x), y: Float(point.y), z: 0.0)
    let scenePos = sceneView.unprojectPoint(unprojectPoint)
    print("2D point: \(point). 3D point: \(scenePos)")
}
```

**Output:**

2D point: (154.5, 169.5). 3D point: SCNVector3(x: -0.00111810782, y:
0.0232769605, z: 7.9000001)

2D point: (280.5, 252.0). 3D point: SCNVector3(x: 0.0244967155, y: 0.00650534919, z: 7.9000001)

2D point: (32.0, 181.0). 3D point: SCNVector3(x: -0.0260214079, y: 0.0209390987, z: 7.9000001)

2D point: (12.0, 505.0). 3D point: SCNVector3(x:
-0.0300872531, y: -0.0449275821, z: 7.9000001)

2D point: (311.5, 12.5). 3D point: SCNVector3(x: 0.0307987742, y: 0.0551938377, z: 7.9000001)

2D point: (22.5, 88.0). 3D point: SCNVector3(x: -0.0279526841, y: 0.0398452766, z: 7.9000001)

2D point: (313.5, 358.0). 3D point: SCNVector3(x: 0.0312053617, y: -0.0150436237, z: 7.9000001)

2D point: (314.0, 507.0). 3D point: SCNVector3(x: 0.0313070044, y: -0.0453341678, z: 7.9000001)

2D point: (155.0, 360.5). 3D point: SCNVector3(x: -0.00101646129, y: -0.0155518558, z: 7.9000001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you use 0 and 1 the values do change for `unprojectPoint.` Using 0 for the Z value represents the point on the near plane while using 1 yields the point on the far plane.

So to return a scene point that is an arbitrary distance from the camera, we developed the following function. We are new to SceneKit so please offer any edits or corrections!

Effectively, you define the ray/line between the near and far points then pick some point along the line.

```
private func touchPointToScenePoint(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> SCNVector3 {
    // Get touch point
    let touchPoint = recognizer.locationInView(sceneView)

    // Compute near & far points
    let nearVector = SCNVector3(x: Float(touchPoint.x), y: Float(touchPoint.y), z: 0)
    let nearScenePoint = sceneView.unprojectPoint(nearVector)
    let farVector = SCNVector3(x: Float(touchPoint.x), y: Float(touchPoint.y), z: 1)
    let farScenePoint = sceneView.unprojectPoint(farVector)

    // Compute view vector
    let viewVector = SCNVector3(x: Float(farScenePoint.x - nearScenePoint.x), y: Float(farScenePoint.y - nearScenePoint.y), z: Float(farScenePoint.z - nearScenePoint.z))

    // Normalize view vector
    let vectorLength = sqrt(viewVector.x*viewVector.x + viewVector.y*viewVector.y + viewVector.z*viewVector.z)
    let normalizedViewVector = SCNVector3(x: viewVector.x/vectorLength, y: viewVector.y/vectorLength, z: viewVector.z/vectorLength)

    // Scale normalized vector to find scene point
    let scale = Float(15)
    let scenePoint = SCNVector3(x: normalizedViewVector.x*scale, y: normalizedViewVector.y*scale, z: normalizedViewVector.z*scale)

    print("2D point: \(touchPoint). 3D point: \(nearScenePoint). Far point: \(farScenePoint). scene point: \(scenePoint)")

    // Return <scenePoint>
    return scenePoint
}
```

Comment: did this solve your issue? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I don't understand the `let scale = Float(15)` part. How does that help you find an arbitrary point? Don't you need to pass in a second argument?