# finding the depth in arkit with SCNVector3Make

Tags: ios, arkit

the goal of the project is to create a drawing app. i want it so that when i touch the screen and move my finger it will follow the finger and leave a cyan color paint. i did created it BUT there is one problem. the paint DEPTH is always randomly placed.

here is the code, just need to connect the sceneView with the storyboard.
  https://github.com/javaplanet17/test/blob/master/drawingar

my question is how do i make the program so that the depth will always be consistent, by consistent i mean there is always distance between the paint and the camera.

if you run the code above you will see that i have printed out all the SCNMatrix4, but i none of them is the DEPTH.

i have tried to change `hitTransform.m43` but it only messes up the x and y.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a point some consistent distance in front of the camera, you don’t want a hit test. A hit test finds the real world surface in front of the camera — unless your camera is pointed at a wall that’s perfectly parallel to the device screen, you’re always going to get a range of different distances.

If you want a point some distance in front of the camera, you need to get the camera’s position/orientation and apply a translation (your preferred distance) to that. Then to place SceneKit content there, use the resulting matrix to set the transform of a SceneKit node.

The easiest way to do this is to stick to SIMD vector/matrix types throughout rather than converting between those and SCN types. SceneKit adds a bunch of new accessors in iOS 11 so you can use SIMD types directly.

There’s at least a couple of ways to go about this, depending on what result you want.

#### Option 1

```
// set up z translation for 20 cm in front of whatever
// last column of a 4x4 transform matrix is translation vector
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
translation.columns.3.z = -0.2

// get camera transform the ARKit way
let cameraTransform = view.session.currentFrame.camera.transform
// if we wanted, we could go the SceneKit way instead; result is the same
// let cameraTransform = view.pointOfView.simdTransform

// set node transform by multiplying matrices
node.simdTransform = cameraTransform * translation
```

This option, using a whole transform matrix, not only puts the node a consistent distance in front of your camera, it also orients it to point the same direction as your camera.

#### Option 2

```
// distance vector for 20 cm in front of whatever
let translation = float3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.2)

// treat distance vector as in camera space, convert to world space
let worldTranslation = view.pointOfView.simdConvertPosition(translation, to: nil)

// set node position (not whole transform)
node.simdPosition = worldTranslation
```

This option sets only the position of the node, leaving its orientation unchanged. For example, if you place a bunch of cubes this way while moving the camera, they’ll all be lined up facing the same direction, whereas with option 1 they’d all be in different directions.

#### Going beyond

Both of the options above are based only on the 3D transform of the camera — they don’t take the position of a 2D touch on the screen into account.

If you want to do that, too, you’ve got more work cut out for you — essentially what you’re doing is hit testing touches not against the world, but against a virtual plane that’s always parallel to the camera and a certain distance away. That plane is a cross section of the camera projection frustum, so its size depends on what fixed distance from the camera you place it at. A point on the screen projects to a point on that virtual plane, with its position on the plane scaling proportional to the distance from the camera (like in the below sketch):

[image: awesome napkin sketch of screen plane projection]

So, to map touches onto that virtual plane, there are a couple of approaches to consider. (Not giving code for these because it’s not code I can write without testing, and I’m in an Xcode-free environment right now.)

1. Make an invisible `SCNPlane` that’s a child of the view’s `pointOfView` node, parallel to the local xy-plane and some fixed z distance in front. Use SceneKit [`hitTest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest) (not ARKit hit test!) to map touches to that plane, and use the `worldCoordinates` of the hit test result to position the SceneKit nodes you drop into your scene.
2. Use Option 1 or Option 2 above to find a point some fixed distance in front of the camera (or a whole translation matrix oriented to match the camera, translated some distance in front). Use SceneKit’s [`projectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint) method to find the normalized depth value *Z* for that point, then call [`unprojectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522631-unprojectpoint) with your 2D touch location and that same *Z* value to get the 3D position of the touch location with your camera distance. (For extra code/pointers, see my similar technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25154025/957768).)

Comment: sorry for late reply, i try up the make invisible SCNPlane option, and then test it by creating a ball wherever i touch the screen, but the longer i touch the screen the ball are quickly getting closer and closer to the screen. here is the new code.    https://github.com/javaplanet17/test/blob/master/drawingar2