# ARSCNView unprojectPoint

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I need to convert a point in the 2d coordinate space of my `ARSCNView` to a coordinate in 3d space. Basically a ray from the point of view to the touched location (up to a set distance away).

I wanted to use `arView.unprojectPoint(vec2d)` for that, but the point returned always seems to be located in the center of the view

`vec2d` is a `SCNVector3` created from a 2d coordinate like this

```
SCNVector3(x, y, 0) // 0 specifies camera near plane
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the desired result?

Comment: Have a look at Crashalots answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150737/how-to-use-ios-swift-scenekit-scnscenerenderer-unprojectpoint-properly :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have at least 2 possible solutions:

## First

Use `hitTest(_:types:)` instance method:

> This method searches for real-world objects or AR anchors in the captured camera image corresponding to a point in the SceneKit view.

```
let sceneView = ARSCNView()

func calculateVector(point: CGPoint) -> SCNVector3? {

    let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(point,
                                           types: [.existingPlane])

    if let result = hitTestResults.first {

        return SCNVector3.init(SIMD3(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x,
                                     result.worldTransform.columns.3.y,
                                     result.worldTransform.columns.3.z))
    }
    return nil
}

calculateVector(point: yourPoint)
```

## Second

Use `unprojectPoint(_:ontoPlane:)` instance method:

> This method returns the projection of a point from 2D view onto a plane in the 3D world space detected by ARKit.

```
@nonobjc func unprojectPoint(_ point: CGPoint, 
            ontoPlane planeTransform: simd_float4x4) -> simd_float3?
```

or:

```
let point = CGPoint()
var planeTransform = simd_float4x4()

sceneView.unprojectPoint(point,
                     ontoPlane: planeTransform)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a empty node infront of camera at 'x' cm offset and making it the child of camera.

```
    //Add a node in front of camera just after creating scene
    hitNode = SCNNode()
    hitNode!.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -0.25)  //25 cm offset
    sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(hitNode!)


func unprojectedPosition(touch: CGPoint) -> SCNVector3 {
    guard let hitNode = self.hitNode else {
        return SCNVector3Zero
    }

    let projectedOrigin = sceneView.projectPoint(hitNode.worldPosition)
    let offset = sceneView.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3Make(Float(touch.x), Float(touch.y), projectedOrigin.z))

    return offset
}
```

[See the Justaline GitHub implementation of the code here](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/justaline-ios/blob/master/ViewControllers/ViewController.swift)